# plotting multiple functions without loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to draw a plot of taylor series(of exp(x)) in several orders, from 2 to 10 without loops.
thank for helping! :)

{this is how i did it with loops }

```
 t=linspace(0,1,1000);
 plot(t,exp(t),'r')
 hold on
 syms x
 for i=1:9
     f(x)=taylor(exp(x),'order',i+1);
     y=f(t);
     plot(t,y)
 end
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it without loops?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without loops, if you don't mind computing the Taylor terms manually:

```
N = 10;
t = linspace(0,1,1000);
f = cumsum(bsxfun(@power, t, (0:N).').*repmat(1./factorial(0:N).',1,length(t))).';
plot(t,f)
```

This exploits the fact that passing a matrix input to `plot` causes each column to be plotted.